# Error with Incompatible Integer to Pointer Conversion

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I try to run this code, I get an error saying that:

> Incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char') to parameter of type 'BOOL *' (aka 'signed char *')

on the line

> [self.MMdelegate addItemViewControllerMM:self didCheck1: checked1 didCheck2: checked2 ];

MatchModeViewController.h

```
@class MatchModeViewController;

@protocol MatchModeViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)addItemViewControllerMM:(MatchModeViewController *)MMcontroller didCheck1:(BOOL *)MMbool didCheck2:(BOOL *)MMbool2;

@end

 @interface MatchModeViewController : UIViewController {

 BOOL checked1;   
 BOOL checked2;

}

@property BOOL checked1;
@property BOOL checked2;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *checkBoxButton1;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *checkBoxButton2;

- (IBAction)checkButton1:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)checkButton2:(id)sender;

@end
```

MatchModeViewController.m

```
@synthesize checkBoxButton1;
@synthesize checkBoxButton2;
@synthesize checked2;
@synthesize checked1;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

checked1 = NO;
checked2 = NO;

    [checkBoxButton1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CheckBox.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    [checkBoxButton2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CheckBox.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];


    UIBarButtonItem *saveButtonMM = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Save" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(saveButtonMMPressed)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = saveButtonMM;

}

-(instancetype) init {
    if (self = [super init]) {

    }
    return self;
   }
   - (void) saveButtonMMPressed {

        if([self.MMdelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(addItemViewControllerMM:didCheck1:didCheck2:)]){

            [self.MMdelegate addItemViewControllerMM:self didCheck1: checked1 didCheck2: checked2 ];

            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"MMNOTIFICATIONNAME" object:nil];
    }

         [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES ];

         [self performSelector:@selector(saveButtonMMPressed) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.25];     
    }
```

I am  a beginner at xcode and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Anywhere you have `BOOL *` you need to get rid of the `*`.

Comment: What does the definition for this method look like: `addItemViewControllerMM:didCheck1:didCheck2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are incorrectly defining your protocol method with pointers to `BOOL`. You want:

```
@protocol MatchModeViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)addItemViewControllerMM:(MatchModeViewController *)MMcontroller didCheck1:(BOOL)MMbool didCheck2:(BOOL)MMbool2;

@end
```

Also update any implementation of this method to get rid of the pointers.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a C question.
Looking at your method:

```
- (void)addItemViewControllerMM:(MatchModeViewController *)MMcontroller didCheck1:(BOOL *)MMbool didCheck2:(BOOL *)MMbool2;
```

it seems that `MMbool` and `MMbool2` are supposed to be output parameters, and you need to pass them by reference.

So, instead of calling like this: `[self.MMdelegate addItemViewControllerMM:self didCheck1:checked1 didCheck2: checked2];`

you should call it like this: `[self.MMdelegate addItemViewControllerMM:self didCheck1:&checked1 didCheck2:&checked2 ];`

Placing that `&` before `checked1` send the reference of the variable instead of the value, so whatever change you make to `checked1` within the method will be visible in the function that called it.

LE:
Or maybe you don't need to pass them by reference. In that case you should redefine the protocol method to `- (void)addItemViewControllerMM:(MatchModeViewController *)MMcontroller didCheck1:(BOOL)MMbool didCheck2:(BOOL)MMbool2;` (without the * which makes the BOOLs  pointers)

Comment: Which one of us is correct? The anticipation is terrible. :) Seriously though, it's hard to tell which way it should be changed.